# IE not displaying the page within iframe

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, iframe

I am currently trying to place https://phishingquiz.withgoogle.com/ into an iframe.

It works correctly within Chrome, but seems to just say loading when viewing it in IE.

I have included the code below:

```
<iframe src="https://phishingquiz.withgoogle.com/" allow-same-origin allow- 
scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-pointer-lock width="1200" 
height="900">
</iframe>
```

I am currently running version 11.0.9600.19236

[image: This is what Chrome displays]

Above is what Chrome displays, which is correct.

[image: This is what IE displays]

Above is what IE displays, which is wrong.

I have tried to using the sandbox attribute to allow-javascript, which i presume it might be coded in that, but still no luck.

Would any one have any ideas?

Comment: I've tested to show the page in an iframe on my side. And this is my testing result:https://i.stack.imgur.com/6COaU.jpg I'd like to ask that which IE version you use. And if possible, please share your detailed code about you show the page. Maybe there is some codes affecting this.

Comment: Hi @JeniferJiang thank you for the comment. I have included the code and version number of IE.

Comment: @JeniferJiang I also have tested the iframe on my personal website and there is no issue, which is odd.

Comment: I'm sorry to forget to ask that when you run the page on IE, is there any error appearing in console column?Maybe like this?https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvoMB.jpg